# historic 'slice' of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

Ms SQL Server.

I have a table that monitors status of applications to school of students.
Students can apply to multiple schools and each one can accept/reject/waitlist the students.

Table `tblApplicantSchools` would look something like this:

```
ApplicantID    |    SchoolID     |     StatusID
```

Unique applicants can appear here applying to multiple schools - but only one status per school application.

I also have a historic table `tblApplicantSchools_shadow`, which shadows any change made on `tblApplicantSchools`. It is identical to the above, except that  it also saves the time the change was made, and whether it was an insert/update/delete on the original table.
So in he `shadow` table, there could be multiple students, to multiple schools with multiple statuses (as they move through the process).

What i would like to do, is slice the `shadow` table up to a certain date, and take the single most recent `statusID` of each application to each school of each applicant. Does this make sense?
For example:

```
ApplicantID    |    SchoolID     |     StatusID       |    ChangeDate
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    11                   2                 3                  22/1/2015
    11                   2                 4                  30/1/2015
    11                   3                 4                  25/1/2015
    11                   3                 6                  29/1/2015
```

So what I would want to see is only rows #2 and #4 above, seen as they are the single most recent update of applicant #11 to each school.

Can someone give me a pointer on how this can be done? My setup is a little more complex, but i think this example simplifies it so that the question is clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would prefer an ANSI-92 compliant solution, or if you are afraid of window functions, then this query might be useful:

```
SELECT s1.ApplicantID, s1.SchoolID, s1.StatusID, s1.ChangeDate
FROM shadow s1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ApplicantID, SchoolID, MAX(ChangeDate) AS maxDate
    FROM shadow
    GROUP BY ApplicantID, SchoolID
) s2
ON s1.ApplicantID = s2.ApplicantID AND s1.SchoolID = s2.SchoolID
    AND s1.ChangeDate = s2.maxDate
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use windowed function [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ApplicantID,SchoolID  
                                       ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC)
      FROM tblApplicantSchools_shadow) AS sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/427302)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ ApplicantID ║ SchoolID ║ StatusID ║     ChangeDate      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════╣
║          11 ║        2 ║        4 ║ 2015-01-30 00:00:00 ║
║          11 ║        3 ║        6 ║ 2015-01-29 00:00:00 ║
╚═════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Keep in mind that if `ChangeDate` is only `DATE`(no time par, there is possibility for tie and you should use `RANK()` instead. With `DATETIME` probability of tie is low.

Comment: This definitely looks like something I want to learn, thank you. Looks like its very powerful. For now too much too swallow and am going for the other more standadr solution.